# Can you write some javascript that will load two separate index.html pages based on URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am working on some merged code that holds 3 applications using phonegap. Although the apps are bundled together they each have their own separate index page. I need to load a different index.html page right off the bat based on a url paramater.  Is it possible to write some js in the head tag to check this, and then load the correct index.html page?

I have been thinking of using something like 
var query= window.location.search.substring(1);
where substring is the extra parameter that signals the app being used. I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I get what you are asking, but give it a go.

First create an array holding the field value pairs from query.

```
var i,
    u = window.location,
    app   = '',
    query = [],
    pairs = u.search.replace(/^\??/, '').split(/[&;]/).map(function(m){
        return m.split(/=/);
    });
```

Giving you an array as in:

```
    pairs <=> 
    [
        [field1, value],
        [field2, value],
        [field3, value]
    ]
```

Then how to proceed is up to how the url is generated in the first place.

Example:

```
/* location.search='?service=app_1&query=do%20this&do=that' */

for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
    if (pairs[i][0] === 'service')
        app = pairs[i][1]; // + optionally push it to query
    else
        query.push(pairs[i].join('='))
}

switch (app) {
case 'app_a1':
    window.location.replace('some_path_1/?' + query.join('&') + u.hash);
    break;
case 'app_a2':
    window.location.replace('some_path_2?' + query.join('&') + u.hash);
    break;
default:
    window.location.assign('some_default_page?bad_request=' +
                            encodeURIComponent(u.href)
    );
    // Or report error here
}
```